# PyQt5 Designer is not working: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

i have a problem with PyQt5 Designer. I install PyQt with -pip install PyQt5 and then -pip install PyQt5-tools
everything OK. But when i try to run Designer it open messagebox with error: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized!
how to deal with it?

Answer (score 26):

1. Go to => 
   ***Python38>lib>site-packages>PyQt5>Qt>plugins***
2. In plugins copy platform folder
3. After that go to
   ***Python38>lib>site-packages>PyQt5_tools>Qt>bin***
4. paste folder here .  Do copy and replace.

This will surely work..
Now you can use designer tool go and do some fun with python...

Comment: I assumed in my case, it would be Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqt5\qt\plugins.....there is no QT directory under pyqt5. Is there something I needed to install before this folder shows up here?

Answer (score 10):

Try running it using command: `pyqt5designer`

It should set all the paths for libraries.

Works on Python 3.8, pyqt5-tool 5.15

Comment: This seems like a much better solution than manually editing the structures of the folders. Tbc you just type in pyqt5designer from the command line, it's not something you import and run from within Python. pyqtdesigner.exe should be in your .../Python38/scripts/ directory if you prefer to run it directly or create a shortcut to it.

Answer (score 4):

I found a way of solving this:

Go to you python instalation folder `Python38\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin`

Then copy all of that files to your clipboard and paste them at `Python38\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools\Qt\bin`

Then open the designer.exe and it should work.

Comment: How to find inst. folder on Win 10 P. 3.7.8?