# Qt Designer does not open (Qt platform plugin could be initialized)

Tags: python, qt-designer

I'm installed `PyQt5` and `pyqt5-tools` by using pip:

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

When I'm trying to open `Qt Designer` from `C:\Program Files\Python\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools\Qt\bin\designer.exe` this error shows:

> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: To open Qt Designer from pyqt5-tools you must run pyqt5designer

Comment: @eyllanesc What do you mean?

Comment: I recommend you read the docs of the libraries you use:  https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/

Comment: I had the same issue and I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61324972/pyqt5-designer-is-not-working-this-application-failed-to-start-because-no-qt-pl)