# Converting python file to .exe using pyinstaller gives: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

[image: error message]

I've created a program using PyQt5 for the user interface, when converting it to a .exe file with pyinstaller (using the line `>pyinstaller --onefile -w --hidden-import=pkg_resources.py2_warn pitch_trainer.py`) I get an executable, however when I try to run it I get the error message shown. I've looked for similar problems, however I can only find examples where the issue is with QT designer (e.g [PyQt5 Designer is not working: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61324972/pyqt5-designer-is-not-working-this-application-failed-to-start-because-no-qt-pl)).

Comment: remove `--onefile` option

Comment: I'll try that now and provide an update

Comment: I still get the same error message

Comment: 1) run from the CMD the command: `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 your.exe`, 2) what files are next to the executable? 3) Use dependency walker to see if any dll is missing

Comment: I get `'QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` If it helps, in the folder containing my exe in the file path C:...\pitch_trainer\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms I have the files qminimal.dll, qoffscreen.dll and qwindows.dll

Comment: okay, then do the following: 1) open cmd, 2) type `set QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` and press enter, 3) copy the full path of the .exe and press enter

Comment: I get this: https://imgur.com/mE40SZm

Comment: don't use the anaconda command prompt but the CMD

Comment: Same issue: https://imgur.com/Az9e73X am I using CMD prompt in the right directory?

Comment: mmm, could you show me an image of the folder where the .exe is?

Comment: Here you go: https://imgur.com/DaQlH18

Comment: Copy folder "C:...\pitch_trainer\PyQt5\Qt\plugins" in the same folder where the .exe is, show me an image of the folder after copying it

Comment: Here's the image: https://imgur.com/HOH1KyF

Comment: I'm assuming you've left now, so thanks very much for taking the time to try help me and I hope a few hours of head banging will fix the problem (although I suspect I'm quite out of my depth on this one)

Answer (score 2):

Update for the unlikely scenario that others are facing the same problem: I found two instances of the plugins folder on my device. One matched the one in the executable (contained `qminimal.dll, qoffscreen.dll and qwindows.dll`) whereas the other was slightly different, containing just `qminimal.dll and qwindows.dll`. I deleted the plugins in my executable folder and replaced it with a copy of the plugins folder at `C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyqt5_tools\Qt\plugins`
This now works without issue, so I guess pyinstaller must have picked out the incorrect (or corrupted) files to build the executable with.